# Database testing tool for AWS RDS proxy

Tags: automated-tests, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy, database-testing

I'm trying to use some automated database testing tool to run tests against RDS proxy, which is connected to an RDS database. I wonder if there is automated database testing tool that would be suitable for running tests against RDS proxy. Thank you in advance.

I was initially using a tool called Benchmark Factory, but it couldn't run against RDS proxy because the test would cause "pinning" of the proxy.